# How to highlight today's date in calendar using python

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

> highlight current date in python using Calendar library.
>   Below is my program.

```
import calendar
c = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.MONDAY)
str = c.formatmonth(2018,1)
print (str)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1dO7.png)

Answer (score 5):

I switched to HTMLCalendar from regular calendar ; added extra html tags around today's date ; displayed new calendar.
It is written for jupyter notebook. it can be done for ipython interactive, but formatting is more cumbersome.

```
    import calendar
    import datetime as dt
    from IPython.display import display,HTML

    # find out today's date
    t = dt.datetime.today()

    # create HTML Calendar month
    cal = calendar.HTMLCalendar()
    s= cal.formatmonth (t.year,t.month)

    # display calendar without highlighting today 
    display(HTML(s))    

    # add cell's backgroundcolor, bold and underling html tags 
    # around today's date
    ss = s.replace('>%i<'%t.day, ' bgcolor="#66ff66"><b><u>%i</u></b><'%t.day)
    display(HTML(ss))
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some explanation along with your code? Code-only answers are not as useful in the long-run as one might expect. Explaining how it works and where it can be used is useful for the community, especially newer users.

Answer (score 3):

A clean and simple solution without workarounds:

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

curr_year = datetime.now().year
curr_month = datetime.now().month
curr_day = datetime.now().day

#ANSI escape sequences for colors
colored_day = '\033[92m' + str(curr_day) + '\033[0m'

calendar_output = (calendar.month(curr_year, curr_month))

#finds occurrences of today's digits inside the year string
count_day_in_year = str(curr_year).count(str(curr_day))

#changes today's digits color only in the right place
if str(curr_day) in str(curr_year):
  #paint day within year (first occurrence(s)) and one more occurrence (the curr. day)
  highlighted_day = calendar_output.replace(str(curr_day), colored_day, count_day_in_year + 1)
  #remove color of the first occurrence(s) in the year
  highlighted_day = highlighted_day.replace('\033[92m', '', count_day_in_year)
  highlighted_day = highlighted_day.replace('\033[0m', '', count_day_in_year)
else:
  highlighted_day = calendar_output.replace(str(curr_day), colored_day, 1)

print(highlighted_day)
```

Result (note the current day 7):

[image]

Comment: This will work, unless the year happens to contain today's date. In that case the replace logic will highlight the digit(s) in the year. Dates that wouldn't work for your example would be 2, 3, 20 and  23rd of February

Comment: Thanks @Lodewyk, you are right. I implemented the necessary corrections in the code to predict days within the year.